# gvNIX/ROO 1.4.1 - NoSuchMethodError avax.persistence.Table.indexes() when adding in Datatables

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, jpa, gvnix

In my project I am successful adding components up to adding in Datatables (web mvc datatables setup). When I do, I get the above exception when deploying the application to **Tomcat** using Oracle DB with the following information:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\prparker\workspaceSTS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\smdms2\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.Table.indexes()[Ljavax/persistence/Index;
```

gvNIX has included the libraries Hibernate Core 4.3.6 and JPA 2.1 1.0.0Final so I don't think it is the issue that has been brought up before.

Thanks for any information.

Comment: So you have some other javax.persistence jar present in the CLASSPATH that does not have that method. Can't get simpler

Comment: You are correct. An added plug-in added the JPA 2.0 library and once it was removed the error went away. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the effective dependencies or the transitive dependencies of your pom.xml. I think you have an inhereted or transitive dependency that includes JPA 2.0 in your project. Exclude it from your pom.xml

Comment: A plug-in added the JPA 2.0 library to the deployment causing the error. Thank you.

Comment: If the answer helps you to close the issue, please you accept it as the resolving answer.